# Enable/Disable LOG levels using C Macro

Tags: c, macros

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG_D(x)  {  printf("D:");  printf(x);}
#define LOG_E(x)  {  printf("E:");  printf(x);}

void test(void)
 {

   LOG_D("ALL is well " );
 }
```

I have a very huge code it has different  levels of log, like above code.
In the final tested library I just need only one error logs in order to reduce the code size .

so I want something like this

```
#define ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG 0
#define ENABLE_ERROR_LOG 1

#define LOG_D(x)  {#if(ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG==1) printf("D:");  printf(x); #endif}
#define LOG_E(x)  {#if(ENABLE_ERROR_LOG==1)  printf("E:");  printf(x);#endif}
```

I added this  #if(ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG==1)  just for explaining, I need some solution which can compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option - you can just comment / uncomment `ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG` and `ENABLE_ERROR_LOG` to disable / enable corresponding log level.

```
// #define ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG    // disable DEBUG_LOG
#define ENABLE_ERROR_LOG       // enable ERROR_LOG

#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG
#define LOG_D(x)  {  printf("D:");  printf(x);}
#else
#define LOG_D(x) // nothing
#endif

#ifdef ENABLE_ERROR_LOG
#define LOG_E(x)  {  printf("E:");  printf(x);}
#else
#define LOG_E(x)  // nothing
#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot nest preprocessor directives. But you can make two versions of your macro and define them in exclusive parts of an `#if` or `#ifdef`:

```
#define ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG 0

#if ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG != 0
#define LOG_D(...)  printf("D: " __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define LOG_D(...)  // Do nothing
#endif
```

Here, the disabled version just "eats" the `LOG_D` macro and doesn't do anything. (Note that undefined macros are treated as the value 0 in `#if` conditionals.)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
#if ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG == 1
#    define LOG_D(x)  {  printf("D:");  printf(x);}
#else
#    define LOG_D(x)
#end
```

That way the debug log statements will just disappear if `ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG` is undefined or has a different value.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you could check the `#ifdef` directive.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* #define DEBUG */

#ifdef DEBUG
#define LOG_D(x) {  printf("D: %s\n",x); }
#define LOG_E(x) {  printf("E: %s\n",x); }
#else
#define LOG_D(x)
#define LOG_E(x)
#endif

int main() {
        LOG_D("blah...");
        return 0;
}
```

If you uncomment the `#define DEBUG` line, the program will print `D: blah...`

Comment: This issue exists with any possible approach. That's just how strings in C work.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the other answers, it is not good idea to define the macros completely empty when they are not enabled, as this would go wrong when error logging is enabled:

```
    if (some_error)
        LOG_E("Oops...");
    do_something();
```

If `LOG_E(x)` expands to nothing, then `do_something()` would only be called if `some_error` is true, which is probably not what you want!

So you could define the "do nothing" variant of `LOG_E(x)` like this:

```
#define LOG_E(x) { }
```

Rather than starting and ending with braces, I tend to use the `do { blah; } while (0)` construct as it forces you to put a semicolon on the end when you use it. Something like this:

```
#if ENABLE_ERROR_LOG
#define LOG_E(x) do { printf("E:"); printf(x); } while (0)
#else
#define LOG_E(x) do ; while (0)
#endif
```

Then,

```
    if (some_error)
        LOG_E("Oops")
```

would result in a syntax error because of the missing semicolon, forcing you to write it as

```
    if (some_error)
        LOG_E("Oops");
```

Another thing you can do is concatenate the `"E:"` or `"D:"` tag with the passed in string, although this requires the parameter to be a string literal, rather than a general `char *`:

```
#define LOG_E(x) printf("E:" x)
```

Another thing you can do is to define the macro with a variable number of parameters (a *variadic* macro) to increase your options:

```
#define LOG_E(...) printf("E:" __VA_ARGS__)
```

Then you can do:

```
    if (some_error)
        LOG_E("Oops, got error: %d\n", some_error);
```

Another thing you can do is let the compiler optimize out the call to `printf` and define it like this:

```
#define LOG_E(...) do if (ENABLE_ERROR_LOG) printf("E:" __VA_ARGS__); while (0)
```

A decent compiler will notice that the `if` condition is constant and either optimize out the call to `printf` completely (if the constant condition is false), or include it (if the constant condition is true). For some compilers, you might need to suppress warnings about constant conditions in an `if` statement.